# Undefined variable when calling fn

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this very simple function in Laravel,

```
public function getImage($slug){

    // This return an error
    $cached = Cache::remember('Test', 10, function(){
        $images = $this->allImages();

        // Undefined var $slug
        return file_get_contents($images[$slug]['image-url']);
    });

    // This works
    // $images = $this->allImages();
    // $cached = file_get_contents($images[$slug]['image-url']);

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type'      =>  'image/jpeg',
        'Cache-Control'     =>  'max-age=600'
    ];

    return Response::make($cached, 200, $headers);
}
```

This might be a stupid a question but i haven't used PHP in a long time, and get around this why $slug is undefined??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an anonymous function/closure that you later pass to **Cache::remember()** you need to explicitely list all the variables from the parent scope that should be available in that function's scope.

**use** statement is used for that - the following code should work:

```
$cached = Cache::remember('Test', 10, function() use($slug) {
    $images = $this->allImages();

    // Undefined var $slug
    return file_get_contents($images[$slug]['image-url']);
});
```

Comment: God bless you sir.